# ALB Ingress Controller on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I'm trying to setup an ALB Ingress Controller on AWS-EKS, exactly as the following tutorial describe: [ingress_controller_alb](https://eksworkshop.com/beginner/130_exposing-service/ingress_controller_alb/), but I cannot get an ingress address.

Indeed, if I run the following command: `kubectl get ingress/2048-ingress -n 2048-game`, after 10 minutes I get no address. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Problem may be in version of aws-controller you are using - you are using old version of ingress controller - 1.0.0, new one is 1.1.3.

I advice you to take look at this documentation: [ingress-controller-alb](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-alb-ingress-controller/guide/controller/setup/).

**1.** Download sample ALB ingress controller manifest

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller/v1.1.3/docs/examples/alb-ingress-controller.yaml
```

**2.** Configure the ALB ingress controller manifest

At minimum, edit the following variables:

```
--cluster-name=devCluster: name of the cluster. AWS resources will be tagged with kubernetes.io/cluster/devCluster:owned
```

If ec2metadata is unavailable from the controller pod, edit the following variables:

```
--aws-vpc-id=vpc-xxxxxx: vpc ID of the cluster.
--aws-region=us-west-1: AWS region of the cluster.
```

**3.** Deploy the RBAC roles manifest

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller/v1.1.3/docs/examples/rbac-role.yaml
```

**4.** Deploy the ALB ingress controller manifest

```
kubectl apply -f alb-ingress-controller.yaml
```

**5.** Verify the deployment was successful and the controller started

```
kubectl logs -n kube-system $(kubectl get po -n kube-system | egrep -o "alb-ingress[a-zA-Z0-9-]+")
```

You should be able to display output similar to the following:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AWS ALB Ingress controller
Release:    1.0.0
Build:      git-7bc1850b
Repository: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller.git
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Then you can deploy sample application**

Execute following commands:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller/v1.1.3/docs/examples/2048/2048-namespace.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller/v1.1.3/docs/examples/2048/2048-deployment.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller/v1.1.3/docs/examples/2048/2048-service.yaml
```

Deploy an Ingress resource for the 2048 game:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller/v1.1.3/docs/examples/2048/2048-ingress.yaml
```

After few seconds, verify that the Ingress resource is enabled:

```
kubectl get ingress/2048-ingress -n 2048-game
```

Comment: I have followed all the above. I am using EKS Fargate. And creating ingress but gives no host address. The error i see in the contoler pod logs is below.

{"level":"error","ts":1643650856.9675832,"logger":"controller-runtime.manager.controller.ingress","msg":"Reconciler error","name":"app-ingress","namespace":"backend","error":"WebIdentityErr: failed to retrieve credentials\ncaused by: RequestError: send request failed\ncaused by: Post \"https://sts.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/\": dial tcp: i/o timeout"}

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issue, but finally got it working after following @MaggieO steps above.  A couple of things to consider:

1. Add public and private subnets to your EKS cluster.  Make sure your public subnets are tagged with "kubernetes.io/role/elb":"1".   If creating a managed node group, only select private subnets for placement of your worker nodes.
2. Make sure your IAM role for you worker nodes has the policies AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy, AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly, AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy, and the custom policy defined here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller/v1.1.2/docs/examples/iam-policy.json.
3. Examine your ingress controller logs, they are helpful.

   kubectl logs -n kube-system [name of your ingress controller]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your replies!

I think the problem is the cluster creation that results in cluster creation without EC2 instances, with the command `eksctl cluster create -f cluster.yaml`

```
apiVersion: eksctl.io/v1alpha5
kind: ClusterConfig
metadata:
  name: test
  region: eu-central-1
  version: "1.14"
vpc:
  id: vpc-50b17738
  subnets:
    private:
      eu-central-1a: { id: subnet-aee763c6 }
      eu-central-1b: { id: subnet-bc2ee6c6 }
      eu-central-1c: { id: subnet-24734d6e }
nodeGroups:
  - name: ng-1-workers
    labels: { role: workers }
    instanceType: t3.medium
    desiredCapacity: 2
    volumeSize: 5
    privateNetworking: true
```

I try with node groups and with managed node groups, but I get the following timeout error:

```
...
[ℹ]  nodegroup "ng-1-workers" has 0 node(s)
[ℹ]  waiting for at least 2 node(s) to become ready in "ng-1-workers"
Error: timed out (after 25m0s) waiting for at least 2 nodes to join the cluster and become ready in "ng-1-workers"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you succeed to create contoller,you will find this controller:

```
$ kubectl get po -n kube-system | grep alb
alb-ingress-controller-669b958f64-p69fw               1/1     Running   0          3m7s
```

and its logs :

```
$ kubectl logs -n kube-system $(kubectl get po -n kube-system | egrep -o alb-ingress[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AWS ALB Ingress controller
  Release:    v1.1.8
  Build:      git-ec387ad1
  Repository: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller.git
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

W0720 13:31:21.242868       1 client_config.go:549] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
```